# Drupal 6: replace jquery version on single page

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

I'm in quite a pickle with a Jquery version bind.  I need to have version 1.4.1 or higher on one specific page, to achieve a particular effect, and I don't see a way to override the Drupal default verion of 1.2.6. for just the one page.  The highest Drupal 6 can seem to handle is v1.3.2, which the [JQ Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) swaps in sitewide.

So is there any way to override the JQ head tag for a particular page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is in a new module.  This is copied and modified from the **jquery update** module.:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_registry_alter().
 *
 * Make my page preprocess function run *after* everything else's.
 */
function my_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['page'])) {
    // If jquery_update's preprocess function is there already, remove it.
    if ($key = array_search('jquery_update_preprocess_page', $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'])) {
      unset($theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][$key]);
    }
    // Now tack it on at the end so it runs after everything else.
    $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][] = 'my_module_preprocess_page';
  } 
}


/**
 * Implementation of moduleName_preprocess_hook().
 *
 * Replace Drupal core's jquery.js with the new one from my module.
 */
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Only do this for a specific page.
$alias_array = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));
if($alias_array[0] == 'special_page') {
  // get the scripts from head.
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();

    $myreplacement = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module').'/jquery-1.4.1.min.js';

    $new_jquery = array($myreplacement => $scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
    $scripts['core'] = array_merge($new_jquery, $scripts['core']);
    unset($scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);

        $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same for D7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Could [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6) work? Replace `$data` with the path to your .js file.

Comment: No, that would just add another jquery file on top of drupal's default, thus causing conflicts.  I'm finding a solution now, and will post it as soon as I test it.  It's just copying and modifying the preprocess hook in the jquery update module.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Michael D is just great. I'll add, i use it not for a single page, but for all the site in front and so, i could keep standard version of Jquery for the backoffice. I do not have any conflict and i use latest version of Jquery.